# Masking DataFrame based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
ID   Status  SP1   SP2  Level
5       I     R     R   D3
5       C     R     R   D2
5       D     R     R   D1
6       C     R     R   D2
6       I     D     D   D4
6       I     S     D   D4
6       D     R     D   D1
7       I     R     D   D3
7       C     D     D   D4
7       D     D     D   D4
```

I want to make change the DataFrame so that if **(1)** `Status`==`D` and `Level`=='D1' then all rows with the same ID will change to `D1`. **(2)** If `Status`==`C` and `Level`=='D2' then all rows with the same ID will change to `D2`.   **(3)** If `Status`==`I` and `Level`=='D3' then all rows with the same ID will change to `D3`.  **(4)** If for each individual `ID` (`Status`==`D` and `Level`==`D1`) AND (`Status` == `C` and `Level`== `D2`) AND  (`Status` == `I` and `Level`== `D3`), then change `Level` to `R`.  So only `ID` number 5 meets the criteria then to change Level to R.

My desired output is :

```
ID   Status  SP1   SP2  Level
5       I     R     R   R
5       C     R     R   R
5       D     R     R   R
6       C     R     R   D1
6       I     D     D   D1
6       I     S     D   D1
6       D     R     D   D1
7       I     R     D   D3
7       C     D     D   D3
7       D     D     D   D3
```

I have completed steps 1-3 with this code:

```
df['mask'] = ((df['STATUS'] == 'D') 
        & df['Level'].isin(['D1']))
mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['mask'].transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'Level'] = 'D1'
del df['mask']


df['mask'] = ((df['STATUS'] == 'C') 
        & df['Level'].isin(['D2']))
mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['mask'].transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'Level'] = 'D2'
del df['mask']


df['mask'] = ((df['STATUS'] == 'I') 
        & df['Level'].isin(['D3']))
mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['mask'].transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'Level'] = 'D3'
del df['mask']
print(df)
```

What I am stuck on is number (4) where I want to change values in `Level` to `R` based on the multiple and's.

Edit:

Another code I tried that should achieve a similar outcome:

```
df['mask'] = ((df['SP1'] != 'D') 
        or df['SP2'] != 'D'))
mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['mask'].transform('any')
df.loc[mask, 'Level'] = 'R'
del df['mask']
```

As long as there is no `D` for a given `ID` I want to make `Level`=`R`  I seem to have syntax errors in the above example though.

Answer (score 0):

You need | instead of or and you're missing a (

```
df['mask'] = ((df['SP1'] != 'D') 
        | (df['SP2'] != 'D'))
```

Boolean operator for or in pandas is |